# amCharts 4 - How to Determine if Cursor is Currenlty Showing?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

How can you check if the cursor is currently showing (i.e. the mouse cursor is over the chart)?

It was suggested [here](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1300) to use:

```
if (cursor.hidden || cursor.isHiding) {
  // nope, cursor is not there
}
```

However, both properties are always false.  See [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQogxb).

With the console open, click the "Get Cursor Info In 2 Seconds" button and do not move the mouse (i.e. keep the mouse cursor off the chart so that the cursor is not displayed). Once the setTimeout is complete, both are reported false in the console.  At least one should be true.

Comment: So you want to hide the mouse cursor when you are over the chart? is that what you want ? if thats the case here is a pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRWpWO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidden` should be `isHidden`.  So this seems to work:

```
if (cursor.isHidden || cursor.isHiding) {
  // nope, cursor is not there
}
```